# jQuery Cycle plugin (or another one as well) for showing more than one item at a time

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I would like to have a slide like the one at the home page of Twitter. This means, to have many posts showing at the same time, and sliding them with a certain interval.

I've checked out the [Cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) of jQuery and I've seen that I could accomplish something like that using the `scrollDown` effect, but the only problem is that one image at a time is being displayed.

Is there any way for showing more than one at a time? Or at least, using another plugin as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you grabbing your new posts?

I'd suggest you look at http://twitterfall.com/ they are simply animating a new post at the top of the list and having it push the other down.

Comment: Yes, I want something like that. Could you tell me how I could get a clue about how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) or another carousel plugin.

Comment: @Claudiu: Yeah it can be annoying to theme though :-) But thats minor in comparison to properly writing your own slide queue.

Comment: My point exactly. I love the thing that it's flexible enough to allow doing preety much anything you need with it and use several sliders on a page without (almost) any problems.

Comment: @Claudiu: Definitely. I once hooked a single set of controls up to 5 different carousel instances (they all needed separate transitions and were structurally in different parts of the page). Im sure this wasnt the most resource efficient way to go about it, but it only took me an hour and a half too set it up and theme it, haha.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's something, haha!

Answer (score 0):

Group several images together. The cycle plugin can cycle anything, not just images.

```
<ul id="the-element-to-cycle">
    <li>
        <img src="..." />
        <img src="..." />
        <img src="..." />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="..." />
        <img src="..." />
        <img src="..." />
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>text only on this one</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```